# DropDownList con Selected Me devuelve Null al hacer post

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy trabajando con ASP.Net MVC 5 y EF6, yo tengo una clase para editar usuarios de la aplicación y relleno en un DropDownList los roles que existen y tiene preseleccionado el rol del usuario, al hacer post seleccionando otro Rol me devuelve una excepción en la vista del tipo null

> Model.RolesList = 'Model.RolesList' inició una excepción de tipo
>   'System.NullReferenceException'

Este es el controlador que trae los datos del usuario a editar:

```
public ActionResult Edit(string Id)
    {
        //var Usuario = ctx.Users.Where(u => u.UserName.Equals(UserName, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).FirstOrDefault();
        var Usuario = UserManager.FindById(Id);

        var UsuarioRol = UserManager.GetRoles(Id).First();

        return View(new EditUsuarioViewModel() {
            Id = Usuario.Id,
            Email = Usuario.Email,
            Nombre = Usuario.Nombre,
            Apellido = Usuario.Apellido,
            AreaId = Usuario.AreaId,
            Alias = Usuario.Alias,
            //RolId = Usuario.RolId,
            //Para el llenado del comboBox de roles
            RolesList = ctx.Roles.ToList().Select(x => new SelectListItem()
            {
                Selected = UsuarioRol.Contains(x.Name),
                Text = x.Name,
                Value = x.Name
            })
        });
    }
```

RolesList devuelve la lista de Roles y preselecciona el rol del usuario, hasta aquí todo funciona correctamente bien, aquí hago el post:

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include= 
        "Id,Email,Alias,Nombre,Apellido,AreaId,RolId")]
        EditUsuarioViewModel editUser)
    {
       if(ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var Usuario = UserManager.FindById(editUser.Id);

            if(Usuario == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }

            Usuario.Email = editUser.Email;
            Usuario.UserName = editUser.Email;
            Usuario.AreaId = editUser.AreaId;
            Usuario.Nombre = editUser.Nombre;
            Usuario.Apellido = editUser.Apellido;
            Usuario.Alias = editUser.Alias;
            Usuario.RolId = editUser.RolId;

            //Verificamos si tiene un rol
            var UsuarioRol = UserManager.GetRoles(editUser.Id);

            //Si tiene rol pues lo quitamos
            if (UsuarioRol != null)
            {
                var quitar = UserManager.RemoveFromRoles(editUser.Id, UsuarioRol.ToArray());
                if(!quitar.Succeeded)
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", quitar.Errors.First());
                    return View();
                }
            }

            //Agregamos el nuevo rol
            var result = UserManager.AddToRole(editUser.Id, editUser.RolId);
            if(!result.Succeeded)
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
                return View();
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ModelState.AddModelError("", "No se pudo realizar los cambios");
        return View();
    }
```

la clase EditUsuarioViewModel:

```
public class EditUsuarioViewModel
{
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Nombre del usuario")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Apellido del usuario")]
    public string Apellido { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Área")]
    public int AreaId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Correo electrónico")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Alias del Usuario")]
    public string Alias { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Rol")]
    public string RolId { get; set; }

    public string Foto { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> RolesList { get; set; }
}
```

En la vista creo el DropDownList así:

```
<div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RolId, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class=" col-md-10">
               <!-- AQUI ES DONDE MARCA EL ERROR -->
               @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.RolId,Model.RolesList,"Seleccione un Rol")  
            </div>
        </div>
```

¿En qué puedo estar fallando?

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

El problema radicaba en que si ocurría algún error en la edición devolvía la lista a la vista como nulo, la solución fue reenviar la lista de nuevo cada vez que se llame a la misma vista:

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
  public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include= 
    "Id,Email,Alias,Nombre,Apellido,AreaId,RolId")]
    EditUsuarioViewModel editUser)
  {
   if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var Usuario = UserManager.FindById(editUser.Id);

        if(Usuario == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }

        Usuario.Email = editUser.Email;
        Usuario.UserName = editUser.Email;
        Usuario.AreaId = editUser.AreaId;
        Usuario.Nombre = editUser.Nombre;
        Usuario.Apellido = editUser.Apellido;
        Usuario.Alias = editUser.Alias;
        Usuario.RolId = editUser.RolId;

        //Verificamos si tiene un rol
        var UsuarioRol = UserManager.GetRoles(editUser.Id);

        //Si tiene rol pues lo quitamos
        if (UsuarioRol != null)
        {
            var quitar = UserManager.RemoveFromRoles(editUser.Id, UsuarioRol.ToArray());
            if(!quitar.Succeeded)
            {
                //Reenviar la lista de nuevo aquí
                ModelState.AddModelError("", quitar.Errors.First());
                return View();
            }
        }

        //Agregamos el nuevo rol
        var result = UserManager.AddToRole(editUser.Id, editUser.RolId);
        if(!result.Succeeded)
        {
            //Reenviar la lista de nuevo aquí
            ModelState.AddModelError("", result.Errors.First());
            return View();
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    //Reenviar la lista de nuevo aquí
    ModelState.AddModelError("", "No se pudo realizar los cambios");
    return View();
}
```